# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(1 + 1)(1 + 1)'

Tags: python, string, recursion, error-handling, int

I'm writing a recursive function that takes a number as an input and returns a string based on the input.

This is my code:

```
def sum_power2( n ): 

    n_int = int( n )

    if n_int == 0:

        return '1'

    else:

        return sum_power2( n_int * '(1 + 1)' )
```

Originally the code was resulting in an error code of

```
    can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

when n was not converted to an 'int' and now I've been getting this error code. Please help me figure it out, thanks!

For and input of **sum_power2(2)** the output should be **'((1 + 1)(1 + 1))'**

Comment: int doesn't evaluate what you wrote in your string, it simply tries to convert it to an int without making any other operation.

If what you want to do is as simple as you show there, using the eval function could be a way to do it, even though it is often not recommended to use it - I can't figure out why, anyone is welcome to clarify.

Comment: @LoicM See  https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: What should `sum_power2(3) ` return?

Comment: @PM2Ring sorry for the late response, but I can't tell you EXACTLY what sum_power2(3) should return because the amount of parenthesis confuses me, but I can tell you that sum_power2(4) returns precisely '((((1+1)+(1+1))+((1+1)+(1+1)))+(((1+1)+(1+1))+((1+1)+(1+1))))'

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you want sum_power2(n) to return n copies of the string (1 + 1), yes?

In that case, the recursive way to do this would be, for n>1, to append the string (1 + 1) to the output of sum_power2(n-1). (This will need a special case to give just 1 when n=0)

That'll look like this:

```
def sum_power2(n):
  if n == 0:
    return "1"
  elif n == 1:
    return "(1 + 1)"
  else:
    return sum_power2(n-1) + "(1 + 1)"
```

(Also, it looks like your argument is an int anyway so I've omitted the conversion)

Comment: this works as it should but there's one minor issue maybe you could help me with. The input of sum_power2(2) returns '(1+1)(1+1)' but expects '((1+1)+(1+1))'

Comment: It looks like the OP wants an extra level of parentheses...  or maybe more.

Comment: Would `sum_power(3)` return `((1+1)(1+1)(1+1))` or `((1+1)((1+1)(1+1)))`?

Comment: @HalfTau a little confusing, but sum_power(3) should return (((1+1)+(1+1))+((1+1)+(1+1)))+(((1+1)+(1+1)))

Comment: @beginner_coder Huh? So how come `sum_power2(2)` is supposed to return `'((1 + 1)(1 + 1))'`, rather than `'((1 + 1)+(1 + 1))'`?

Comment: @beginner_coder , can you count opening and closing brackets and and plus signs and make sure they are correct? may be update question with  output for first few  numbers to get an understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your main issue was you were trying to feed in a combination of `int` and `string` to recursive function which is expecting a `int`.
For a recursive function to work , you need to reduce your original problem to a base case and the exit.
I simply reduced *n* to *1* and exited and concatenated our result to be returned upon hitting base case.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

** EDIT **
**Working Code:**
def sum_power2( n ):

```
n_int = int( n )

if n_int == 0:
    return '1'
elif n_int == 1:
    return '(1 + 1)'
else:
    return '(1 + 1)' + sum_power2( n_int - 1 )
```

print sum_power2( 2 )

**Result:**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
1
(1 + 1)
(1 + 1)(1 + 1)
(1 + 1)(1 + 1)(1 + 1)
>>>
```

Comment: This works really well for everything, but 0. If n_int == 0 it should return '1' but with you code, if that returns '1' the output of sum_power2( 2 ) is '(1 + 1)(1 + 1)1'

Comment: Close, but you need to return '1' for an arg of 0. And you can get rid of the n_int stuff, that's only there because the OP was confused about how to fix the problem. You can assume n is an int.

Comment: The easy way to fix it is to have two base cases,  1 and 0.

Comment: Yeah , Noticed that- was away for few mts and looks like someone beat me. No issues, work comes first.

Comment: @Anil_M It's close! You're code returns '(1+1) + (1+1)' for input sum_power2(2), but it should return  '((1 + 1)(1 + 1))'

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_power2( n ): 
    n_int = int( n )
    if n_int == 0:
        return '1'
    else:
        return n_int * '(1 + 1)'
```

`>>> sum_power2(2)
'(1 + 1)(1 + 1)'`

Your error happens because you call `sum_power2( n_int * '(1 + 1)' )`.

Comment: Thanks, but the whole point is that I'm supposed to use a recursive function!

Comment: You cannot use recursive function because you cannot convert `n_int = int( n )`  to int when it takes `'(1 + 1)'` value.

Comment: Before I converted it though I would get the error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'"